# ASP.NET Identity Create Multiple Users

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I am running this code to seed my database, but the data is not being written. When add users individually (outside the ForEach loop), it works. Is there any reason why this doesn't work

```
List<String> usersList = GetAllUsers();

        foreach (string s in usersList)
        {
            var newUser = new ApplicationUser();
            newUser.UserName = s;
            newUser.Email = s;
            var userResult = UserManager.Create(newUser, "greenford");

            //Add User Role Applicant
            if (userResult.Succeeded)
            {
                var result = UserManager.AddToRole(newUser.Id, "Applicant");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is `userResult.Succeeded` false? Is there an error inside it?

Comment: Upon debugging, I have discovered the problem. I was trying to set an email addresses as usernames but it only allows letters and digits.